# Android: Intent Does Not Start After SQLite Query Match

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm attempting to search my bookmarks/browser history for specific URL's then start a new intent after a match is found. The problem is - the new intent never starts - although both the browser history and bookmarks contain the values being queried.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
import com.parse.ParseObject; 
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Service_class extends Service {
       String Dirty1 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty2 = "www.penthouse.com";
        String Dirty3 = "www.pornhub.com";
        String Dirty4 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty5 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty6 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty7 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty8 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty9 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty10 = "www.playboy.com";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                String urls = "";
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String url1 = null;
                String url2 = null;
                do {
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

                if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
                //if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Filthy)) {
                urls = urls
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE)) + " : "
                + url + "\n";
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
                Service_class.this.startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(intent2);
                }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
            //  tv.setText(urls);


    }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
 if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1) || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2) || ....)
 {
     Intent intent2 = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
     intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent2);
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error stating: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? ...even though I've added: intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: I did not pay attention but what is intent in Service_Class.this.startActivity(intent)? Do you really want to start 2 activities at the same time? I edited the answer to take out the first startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You're only going to run the activity if it matches dirty10.  That can be problem 1.

A better way to do this may be to do a rawQuery and use a LIKE statement in your WHERE clause.

And another problem you'll have soon is that if you have multiple hits (after fixing your if/elseifs) you'll launch multiple activities, which is not what you want.